# VB Script for checking the existence of Multiple Files in a Folder

Tags: vbscript

I am Interested in learning how I can check if Multiple Files exist in the following directory: D:\Files to Move\

I have this script which is the first part which moves the file from 1 place to another. This other Place will be my archive folder. I am going to schedule this script so that each day only new files are existing here: D:\Files to Move.

The Issue I am having is trying to understand how I can check if 4 files have been put into this folder? I am going to schedule this task so do not need to specify the time in the script I do not believe. Can anyone help with this please?

```
 with createobject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
.MoveFile "D:\Files to Move\*.*", "D:\Move Files Here"
 End With
```

Comment: Please don't update the original code in the question as it invalidates the original question and confuses others who come across it looking for a similar answer. Have rolled back to the previous revision. Would recommending reading [ask] before posting or checking [meta] for the type of question edits that are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Dim objFso : Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'you can take this as input too using InputBox
Dim strFolderPath : strFolderPath = "D:\Files to Move\" 

'this will error if folder doesn't exist.
Dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strFolderPath) 

'display number of files in the folder.
MsgBox objFolder.Files.Count
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have amended my code. Instead of me using Msgbox is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Well you'd have to define "better".